# c# Regular Expression: print strings different from the pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying using Regular Expression and I have the following string:

```
M3A4S0S3I2M1O4
M3a4s0s3i2m1o4   
m3a4s0s3i2m1o4
F3a4i0l4l1a6
30470041106042700156
30470031201042506146
```

The string pattern is `string pattern = @"\D";` and I want to print:

```
M3A4S0S3I2M1O4
M3a4s0s3i2m1o4
m3a4s0s3i2m1o4
F3a4i0l4l1a6
```

Because it finds matches in this string. I don't print `30470041106042700156`
`30470031201042506146` because it doesn't find any matches.
I write the code:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"\D";
        string input = @"M3A4S0S3I2M1O4 M3a4s0s3i2m1o4 m3a4s0s3i2m1o4    F3a4i0l4l1a6 30470041106042700156 30470031201042506146";
```

But I don't know how can I finish it. How can I fix?

Comment: You want to process a multiline string, or just test against separate lines? Should it be `List<string> input = new List<string>() { "M3A4S0S3I2M1O4",  ... }`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string[] input = { "M3A4S0S3I2M1O4", "M3a4s0s3i2m1o4", "m3a4s0s3i2m1o4", "F3a4i0l4l1a6", "30470041106042700156", "30470031201042506146" };
        foreach (var line in input)
            if (Regex.IsMatch(line, @"\D"))
                Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
M3A4S0S3I2M1O4
M3a4s0s3i2m1o4
m3a4s0s3i2m1o4
F3a4i0l4l1a6
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a regex here actually, use a simple split, join and LINQ:

```
string input = @"M3A4S0S3I2M1O4
M3a4s0s3i2m1o4
m3a4s0s3i2m1o4
F3a4i0l4l1a6
30470041106042700156
30470031201042506146";
string res = string.Join("\r\n", input.Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
       .Where(line => !line.All(Char.IsDigit))
       .ToArray());
```

The `.Where(line => !line.All(Char.IsDigit))` part only keeps the lines that are not all-digits.

If you have a list of strings, replace `string.Join("\r\n", input.Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)` with your list variable and omit `string.Join`.

[image]